# IndexOf not working with getRawValue() in angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, indexof

I've this simple Person interface

```
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Address } from './address';

export class Person {
  id: FormControl<number>;
  name: FormControl<string>;

  addressList: FormArray<FormGroup<Address>>;
}
```

And I am initializing it:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    // initialize person
    this.person = this.fb.group<Person>({
      id: new FormControl<number>(1, { nonNullable: true }),
      name: new FormControl<string>('Usama', { nonNullable: true }),

      // initialize addressList
      addressList: this.fb.array<FormGroup<Address>>([
        this.fb.group<Address>({
          id: new FormControl<number>(1, { nonNullable: true }),
          name: new FormControl<string>('Okara', { nonNullable: true }),
        }),

        this.fb.group<Address>({
          id: new FormControl<number>(2, { nonNullable: true }),
          name: new FormControl<string>('Lahore', { nonNullable: true }),
        }),
      ]),
    });

    this.filter();
  }
```

The problem is with indexOf function in the following snippet. It returns correct results with `value` and incorrect when using `getRawValue()`

```
filter() {
    let obj = this.person.controls.addressList.controls[0]; 
    let add1 = this.person.controls.addressList.value.indexOf(obj.value); //works fine
    let add2 = this.person.getRawValue().addressList.indexOf(obj.getRawValue()); //does not works as expected

    console.log(add1); // returns 0 ---correct result
    console.log(add2); // returns -1 ---incorrect result
  }
```

Comment: you shouldn't use indexOf at all, object ain't supposed to be compared using ===. `The indexOf() method compares searchElement to elements of the array using strict equality (the same algorithm used by the === operator). - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf`

Comment: that's why you shouldn't care at all. you want to know it work or doesn't work, there's only 1 way, dig into the source code. we don't want that, and by not using the use cases that do not designed for, you can save times scratch your head finding the "why"

Answer (score 0):

getRawValue returns a different object

```
let add2 = this.person.getRawValue().addressList.findIndex(address=> address.id === obj.value.id);
```

Comment: @Alexender after we apply `getRawValue()` to `this.person`, `addressList` holds JSON of `this.person`. and we can't add `.value` to JSON array.

Comment: Please check the running example here for clarity: [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g4mawk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fperson.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Yeah I did not check the code.(txh for the stackblitz) getRawValue will return a different object than obj so it will not find it. You should compare based on the id

Comment: Yes, but we also have getRawValue() with `obj`, so objects on both sides are the same. FindIndex will work fine here, the question is why `indexOf` doesn't..

`let add2 = this.person.getRawValue().addressList.indexOf(obj.getRawValue());`

Comment: I can't see `getRawValue()` returning a different object in [Angular's github repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e59406f5e7d1c1cf9bdd7a2f882d05fbf0abcf99/packages/forms/src/model/abstract_model.ts#L1025)